# CSS Media Query Level 4 Range Context Syntax -- not implemented in Chromium?

Tags: css, media-queries, chromium

CSS Media Queries Level 4 introduced a new syntax called "range context" so that you can write them in a much more straightforward, mathematical way. Here's an example *taken straight from the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Syntax_improvements_in_Level_4)*:

```
@media (30em <= width <= 50em ) { ... }
```

It appears the syntax received candidate recommendation status around 2017, and I can find blog posts from around that period with people saying good things about the new syntax.

However, the new syntax doesn't appear to work at all in any Chromium-based browser or Safari, only in Firefox.  The [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Syntax_improvements_in_Level_4) makes no mention of browser support (or lack thereof), I can't figure out how to look at just the "range context" syntax on CanIUse, and I can't find any articles or bug reports or issues talking about support (or lamenting lack thereof).

Can anyone shed light on this? Are the other browser makers working on it? Is there some politics happening with the new syntax?

Or am I just doing it wrong?  Here's a link to a *super simple [fiddle showing it not working (except in Firefox)](https://jsfiddle.net/wqm178yj/1/)*. Could it be I'm misunderstanding the MDN docs, or is it behind an experimental flag or something?

Comment: "Why isn't there content on the web yet about X new feature" seems like it can only have speculative or opinion-based answers. FWIW, the "range" feature is not listed on CanIUse at all; they mostly run off of the contents/compat info on MDN, which you've already mentioned is missing info on it.

Comment: MDN, though, is crowd-editable like Wikipedia. If you've found a feature that's missing from the [media query page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) there, feel free to edit the page (while complying with content and style requirements) to add that missing content.

Comment: Finally, if you find it's not working in Chrome, file a bug with their bug tracker and they'll either classify it as a breakfix or an implementation bug and it should get fixed/added eventually (at least that's how most browsers work; I know Chrome likes to do whatever they want sometimes, standards be darned).